# force use of javascript in a web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a website functions if a file is enabled javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jquery, ajax or javascript    
</script>
```

if my file

```
body{
    display:block;
    }
```

if not my JS file that is not displayed

```
body{
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: So do it. Set the display to none with CSS, then to block with JavaScript.

Comment: what I mean is that if a file is missing JS not display the web

Comment: Not sure if I understood, you mean if a JS file fails to load/execute you want to hide the webpage?

Comment: It's "a website". The web itself is huge.

Comment: if a JS file is missing,the web is not displayed

Comment: @avril alejandro: Try change your mind. Instead of thinking "if a JS file is missing, the web is not displayed" try think this way: "Do not display web until JS is present"

Comment: `<script src="save.js"></script>` if I forget to put the file that the web is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to solve this:

```
<html>
<head>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload= function(){
            document.body.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>        
</head>
<body style="display:none">
   something
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that, but I'm sure that in this case it won't really be an issue. Moreover – this is just a code for illustration purposes, one could also argue there is not doctype, the Javascript code should be in a separate file and so on.

Comment: what I mean is that if a file is missing JS not display the web

Comment: `<script src="save.js"></script>` if I forget to put the file that the web is not displayed

Comment: Then why don't you for example enter this "body showing logic" into the save.js script? Start the page with display:none as I shown and then in save.js change to display:block

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the body to `display:none`, then use JavaScript to show it, using `display:block`.

Of course, anyone with any knowledge of how to use developer tools can just set it to `block` manually...

**JFFiddles:**

- [JSFiddle demonstrating behavior with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/2gHLx/)
- [JSFiddle demonstrating behavior without JS](http://jsfiddle.net/2gHLx/1/)

Comment: what I mean is that if a file is missing JS not display the web

Comment: Right.  If the JS file is missing, the line to make the page visible will not be executed, thereby leaving the page blank.